# AutoFilter based on variable criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Since i'm new to VBA coding i'm tring to write a code that filter data based on variable cells comes from another filter in the same sheet, but keep replyig with the first value only of the selected criteria, any suggestions?

[image]

```
Sub FilterCriteria()
Dim vCrit As Variant
Dim wsO As Worksheet
Dim wsL As Worksheet

Dim rngOrders As Range
Set wsO = Worksheets("Orders")
Set wsL = Worksheets("Lists")
Set rngOrders = wsO.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion

rngOrders.AutoFilter _
Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("51", "55", "71"), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues


Dim rngCrit As Range
Set rngCrit = wsO.Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

rngOrders.AutoFilter Field:=6 'To remove other filter to be able to look up in the whole sheet

vCrit = rngCrit.Value

rngOrders.AutoFilter _
    Field:=4, _
    Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(vCrit), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the filtered range to visible cells only using .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) but
that can give you a non-contiguous range like $D$1:$D$2,$D$6,$D$9 with multiple areas which needs to
be treated differently to a contiguous range like $DS1:$D$9. One way would be to
loop through the cells in that range and build an array for the 2nd filter. For example

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterCriteria()
    Dim vCrit As Variant
    Dim wsO As Worksheet
    Dim wsL As Worksheet

    Dim rngOrders As Range
    Set wsO = Worksheets("Orders")
    Set wsL = Worksheets("Lists")
    Set rngOrders = wsO.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion

    Dim rng As Range
    rngOrders.AutoFilter _
        Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("51", "55", "71"), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Set rng = rngOrders.Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'Debug.Print rng.Address

    Dim arr() As String, cell As Range, i As Integer
    If rng.Cells.Count > 2 Then
        ReDim arr(rng.Cells.Count - 2)
    Else 
        ReDim arr(0)
    End If

    i = 0

    ' build array
    For Each cell In rng
       If i > 0 Then ' skip header
           arr(i - 1) = cell.Value
       End If
       i = i + 1
    Next
    'Debug.Print Join(arr, ",")

    rngOrders.AutoFilter Field:=6 'To remove other filter to be able to look up in the whole sheet
    rngOrders.AutoFilter _
        Field:=4, _
        Criteria1:=arr, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Comment: i'm trying the changes you made but the message "subscript out of range" popup after finishing this line `For Each cell In rng
   If i > 0 Then ' skip header
        arr(i - 1) = cell.Value
   End If
   i = i + 1
Next`

Comment: @menaafraim8 Have you made any changes to it ?

Comment: @menaafraim8  Add MsgBox LBound(arr) & "-" & UBound(arr) after i=0 and tell me what you get

Comment: 0-1 just appeared

Comment: @menafraim8 OK, found the error. See updated code for change to ReDim,